# how i can fetch user data in a manyToMany association

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I have a problem with CakePHP. I tested many ways, but can't find a solution for it.
I have these tables:

**users**

```
id
name
country_code
```

**countries**

```
code
title
```

**skills**

```
code
title
```

**roles**

```
id
title
```

**events**

```
id
title
country_code
```

**events_users**

```
event_id
user_id
role_id
skill_code
```

---

events hasAndBelongsToMany users and events_users is my join table, and when I read data, it gives me something like this:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Event' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'title' => '40th WorldSkills Competitions',
            'year' => '2011',
            'country_code' => 'LV',
            'created' => '2013-02-08 00:00:00'
        ),
        'User' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'password' => '*****',
                'id' => '14',
                'name' => 'test',
                'family' => 'testian',
                'username' => 'test@mail.me',
                'country_code' => 'BR',
                'telphone' => '465465',
                'avatar' => 'avatar_51299c1da268f20110912043238_rodekamp_04.jpg',
                'address' => 'AA',
                'admin' => '0',
                'created' => '2013-02-24 05:50:37',
                'modified' => '2013-02-24 05:50:37',
                'EventsUser' => array(
                    'id' => '1',
                    'user_id' => '14',
                    'event_id' => '1',
                    'role_id' => '1',
                    'skill_code' => '17',
                    'manage' => '100'
                )
            ),
            (int) 1 => array(
                'password' => '*****',
                'id' => '5',
                'name' => 'John',
                'family' => 'Smith',
                'username' => 'john@me.com',
                'country_code' => 'IE',
                'telphone' => '147',
                'avatar' => '20120504124040_franziska_peter_ok.jpg',
                'address' => 'No 55',
                'admin' => '0',
                'created' => '2013-02-10 15:24:13',
                'modified' => '2013-02-10 15:28:50',
                'EventsUser' => array(
                    'id' => '2',
                    'user_id' => '5',
                    'event_id' => '1',
                    'role_id' => '2',
                    'skill_code' => '17',
                    'manage' => '0'
                )
            ),
            (int) 2 => array(
                'password' => '*****',
                'id' => '4',
                'name' => 'hadi',
                'family' => 'mm',
                'username' => 'design.zerzem@gmail.com',
                'country_code' => 'AE',
                'telphone' => '415456',
                'avatar' => '',
                'address' => 'sadjfklsaf asd f',
                'admin' => '0',
                'created' => '2013-02-10 09:01:28',
                'modified' => '2013-02-24 06:43:42',
                'EventsUser' => array(
                    'id' => '3',
                    'user_id' => '4',
                    'event_id' => '1',
                    'role_id' => '4',
                    'skill_code' => '17',
                    'manage' => '0'
                )
            )
)
```

It's ok, but with events_users I want get data about skill and role that are in events_users (skill_code and role_id). How should I create models to give me all this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think reading about ["hasMany Through"](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through-the-join-model) should answer your question.

Basically, you make a model for your join table, then you can associate it like any other model.

When you go to retrieve your data, use [CakePHP's Containable behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) (if you haven't used it before, be prepared to get addicted to it).